# Bigquery data loading ignore pipe and quote

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I try to load data from gcs to bigquery.

I have a pipe | and a quote inside a value like  "247-"001-140-60 | 140-60    "

How should I set up my bigquery.LoadJobConfig to ignore pipe |  and a quote inside  a value. My delimiter is pipe. below is my current config.

```
 if schema:
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema  ,field_delimiter='|',allow_jagged_rows = True,ignore_unknown_values=True,max_bad_records=10)
        # job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema  ,field_delimiter='|',allow_jagged_rows = True)
    else:
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(field_delimiter='|',allow_jagged_rows = True,ignore_unknown_values=True,max_bad_records=10)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with headers. Also are you having this kind of value in only one column or in multiple columns?

Comment: Only in one column